# What is the maximum and minimum value of logarithmic negativity measured for bi-party entanglement?

Tags: superconducting-quantum-computing, entanglement-negativity

I have calculated logrithmic negativity for my biparty entangled system in a superconducting circuit. The negativity gives a sine curve where maximum value comes out to be 4 and minimum 0.5. Now, how can I know it's a substantial value or not?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please add more details of your calculation?

Comment: Hi, i am using Heisenberg-lengvin equations from which i have extracted covariance matrix and from it's eigenvalue the Logarithmic negativity is extracted using conventional mathematics.